# Can I omit the second noun in どのかばんが森さんのかばんですか？

Tags: particle-の

I know in the sentence pattern: Noun の Noun, you can omit the second noun if the context clearly tells what or whom you’re referring to.

そのかばんが森さんのかばんです。
becomes
そのかばんが森さんのです。

Can I do the same with どの？
どのかばんが森さんのかばんですか。
to
どのかばんが森さんのですか.

Comment: @macraf Puzzled. Why do you think this sentence is ungrammatical?

Comment: @user3856370 I must have misread the sentence in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> そのかばんが森さんのかばんです。 becomes そのかばんが森さんのです。

Right.  That is because 「森{もり}さんの」 can denote both the adjectival "Mori's" and the nominal "Mori's belonging".  This is the same when a personal pronoun is used instead of a name.  「わたしの」 can mean both "my" and "mine".

It is also because it is a bit awkward to use the noun 「かばん」 twice in such a short sentence.

> Can I do the same with どの？ どのかばんが森さんのかばんですか。 to どのかばんが森さんのですか.

Yes, you can.  「どのかばんが森さんのですか。」 is a perfectly-formed sentence.

Another natural-sounding way to say that would be 「どれが森さんのかばんですか。」